# Deserialize a string bytes into BitStream

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is as follows:
I serialize the data and send them to PlayerPrefs

```
BitStream bitStream = new BitStream(isTypeSafe);
        bitStream.WriteByte(species);
        bitStream.WriteInt32(revision);
PlayerPrefs.SetString(species.ToString(), bitStream.ToString());
```

and then I try to deserialize data:

```
BitStream bitStream = new BitStream(isTypeSafe);
bitStream.WriteString(PlayerPrefs.GetString(species.ToString()));
species = bitStream.ReadByte();
revision = bitStream.ReadInt32();
```

But the output I get incorrect data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem here is that you use strings as a storage for binary data. This is wrong because changing string encoding can occur which will ruin your data. Unfortunately, `PlayerPrefs` doesn't provide any way to save/load binary data. Thus, the solution would be to use textual serialization instead.

P.S. This looks incorrect:

```
bitStream.WriteString(PlayerPrefs.GetString(species.ToString()));
```

Comment: I do not quite understand your answer. Could you give an example of code? PlayerPrefs.SetInt not appropriate, in my line of bytes stored.

Comment: What values can `species` take? If only a few, then `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` fits perfectly. If many (or if you want generic solution) then, yes, you need serialization. But `BitStream` is a wrong choice. I would also say, that binary serialization is a wrong choice also. What I would recommend to use is some kind of textual serialization (XML or JSON for example).

Comment: I have a lot of different types, not one Int. But I need only BitStream and I do not know how my case, the correct issue deserialize.

Comment: Why do you "need only BitStream"?

Comment: One thing. Are we talking about `UnityEngine.BitStream`?

Comment: Obviously not. What is `BitStream`?

Comment: Yes we talking about UnityEngine.BitStream

Comment: pardon me uLink.BitStream, вы знаете русский?

Comment: I know Russian but it's mandatory to use English on this site. Sorry for that :)